# how to justify rtl text in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app that code just in LTR. so all of my view sets LTR. in one of my screen, I wanna write RTL content that must be justify. and when set `textAlign:'justify'` every thing is great except last line of text. last line give LTR direction and goes left.
I tried to change direction with `I18nManager` but all of my app goes ltr.is there a way to use RTL justify text in just one screen?